# Setting fix for terminal color in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, colors

I just started to download vscode minutes ago. However, I am having a problem with my terminal in vscode where it is just plain white, including the path text. This is the opposite of a youtube video I watched. His path text is colored like when he types "cd" in the terminal, it's yellow. How can I fix this problem?

Image showing text without color in terminal:
[image]

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Okay sorry, but the picture just shows that the path text is not colored

Comment: That is generally terminal dependent. Are you sure the terminal in the youtube video is the same as yours (powershell)?

Comment: If its not the same, how can I edit the default settings since its terminal dependent?

Comment: You could always ask the author of the video about the terminal used in the video, and the settings for that terminal or VSCode.

Comment: "*how can I edit the default settings since its terminal dependent*". Not all terminals will work for you. For example, if they are running a Linux terminal then of course that won't work for you automatically in Windows (unless you install something else like WSL).